# Standardised text editing behaviour across Mac applications

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I've switched over to a Mac recently and, although things have been going quite well, the very different text-editing behaviours across applications is driving me insane.

<kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>Page Up</kbd>, <kbd>Page Down</kbd>, <kbd>Apple-arrow</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-arrow</kbd>, <kbd>alt-arrow</kbd> etc. quite often do different things depending on the application.

Is there a way to standardise this behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are standards, but they are not based around what you're used to from windows. It drove me mad until I got over myself and decided to learn what the actual standards were. Since then I've been sold.

The ones I use:

- <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> - Jump to start/end of line

  - Can also do this with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>/<kbd>e</kbd> which is great if you're used to ssh
- <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> - Jump to top/bottom of text field or document
- <kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> - Jump to start/end of word or previous/next word

These basically replace <kbd>home</kbd>/<kbd>end</kbd>/<kbd>pgup</kbd>/<kbd>pgdown</kbd>, and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>left</kbd>/<kbd>right</kbd> from the windows world.

I find this to be a massive win due to the fact I have a macbook pro and almost no laptops have proper <kbd>home</kbd>/<kbd>end</kbd>/<kbd>pgup</kbd>/<kbd>pgdown</kbd> keys - not needing them in OSX is a godsend

[Here's a big list of the rest of them](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/Site/System%20Bindings.html)

Answer (score 0):

And what's funny (and frustrating!) is that the Microsoft **OS X** apps (e.g. Entourage) use the **Windows** standards.

I develop on WinXP during the day but have an iMac at home, so it's confusing enough trying to switch modes between work and home.  But then I have to remember if I'm writing an e-mail in Entourage, I need to revert back to Windows mode.

I can't think of any good reason why MS wouldn't follow the OS X keyboard standards...